# How to determine the correct amount of oversampling (in regression)

Tags: r, regression, caret, oversampling

For my regression problem I splitted my dataset into a stratified train- and testset (70:30) and I now want to train my models (random forest, gbm, logistic regression) using the trainset. The dataset (~400 obs) contains performance data of subjects in different tasks and these performances should be used to predict a certain skill, hence are used to train the models. I want the models to perform especially good for predicting low-performer subjects. In the histogram below you can see what I consider a low-performer  (red square) and I'm afraid that due to the imbalanced dataset the models fail to deliver good results for this "minority class".

[image]

Therefore, I wrote a function to oversample the evaluation set while training the models using `caret` and `UBL` in `R`.

However, I struggle to find any information on how to determine how much oversampling is okay/allowed/useful.

Note: Hints to sources I can read regarding this topic are also very appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: The exact extend of oversampling (as well as undersampling) is very much depended on your data and your classifier. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a magic number. From personal experience though I can say that an oversampling factor of around 2 is generally safe. Important is to have a well balanced set with which you could manually experiement for a good heuristic. Just notice it could lead to overfitting the test set, so use either a validation set if you have enough data, or an n-fold random spliiting scheme. Good luck